# How can a build a jar with the maven assembly plugin that does not package any dependencies?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Maven assembly plugin has a predefined descriptor for jar-with-dependencies but not a jar-without-dependencies.

I know there is an exclusion config but wild cards do not seem to work with exclusions. Or I am not using them right.

```
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

Comment: the regular jar is also produced along with `artifact-name-jar-with-dependecied.jar`, check your target folder. You could just use that.

Comment: My project normally builds a war file for a webserver, I need the assembly plugin to package the jar to use in dependent projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use assembly plugin, your scenario may be covered by maven-war-plugin with attachedClasses parameter and a classifier, see FAQ on site: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/faq.html#attached